# Run script as admin but show info on current logged in user

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, powershell, batch-file

I am usually running scripts as an admin on a domain which takes a while to finish what they are doing. e.g. Uninstall a version of Office and install another.

These scripts (powershell and bat mostly) as I mentioned before run as admin in a different user session than the currently logged on user.

Is there a way to display information, through that script, to the user,  that is currently logged on?

In any form or shape which is not too distractive, e.g. I would prefer a message box, a tray balloon etc.

Their credentials are unknown to me.

Msg.exe while does transfer information, I was looking for something more interactive, if possible.

Comment: RunAs outputs to the user which was started application/script using it (by hands or by any autobat) undependent by the user used in its parameters...

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?   Alert the user that the script is running? Unless you are hiding the console window of that script, that console will be displayed regardless.

Comment: if the script is running under UserA then UserB won't see a thing.

Comment: @Sonamor How did you launch this script ? can you provide us some code from it ?

Comment: The code is deployed through QUEST KACE SMA (formerly DELL), but it could just be a Logon script or a GPO. The code doesn't really matter it could as well be just a message box where I can read the output.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good application for the [`msg`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/msg) utility. To pop up a message box saying "I did the thing!" in the current interactive session, use this command:

```
msg console I did the thing!
```

You can also make the message box automatically vanish after a specified number of seconds using the `/time` switch. For example, this message will only stay up for ten seconds:

```
msg console /time:10 This message will self-destruct in 10 seconds.
```

Comment: Hi Ben, I should have added this on my original question but I was already aware of the msg.exe. I was looking for something more interactive like a progress bar or a message box where I can get the button thst was pressed.

Comment: @Sonamor Ah, that is indeed a bit of a different question. If you just want to wait until the user acknowledges the message box, you can supply the `/w` switch to `msg`. Beyond that, you'll probably need to rig up some file-based data transfer mechanism and use [`psexec`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) to launch a custom program/script.

Comment: I thought that would be the case as I have done extensive research before coming here. I wasn't aware of the /w switch though, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize this function to get the user physically logged in to the console. I have a few apps where this is needed.

```
Function CurrentUser{
#CurrentUser function converts the username object string "@{username=domain\user}" 
#         to the exact logon string "user" like the example below
#@{username=DOMAIN\USER}
#@{username DOMAIN\USER}
#DOMAIN\USER}
#DOMAIN\USER
#DOMAIN USER
#USER
$loggedInUserName = get-wmiobject win32_computersystem | select username
$loggedInUserName = [string]$loggedInUserName
$loggedinUsername = $loggedInUserName.Split("=")
$loggedInUserName = $loggedInUserName[1]
$loggedInUserName = $loggedInUserName.Split("}")
$loggedInUserName = $loggedInUserName[0]
$loggedInUserName = $loggedInUserName.Split("\")
$loggedInUserName = $loggedInUserName[1]
Return $loggedInUserName
}
```

Reference: [enter link description here](http://tiftomorrow.blogspot.com/2017/03/sccm-ps-detection-method-for-user.html)

Comment: Ok? That will give you the logged in user on the system rather than your admin account, you can't really interact with it or send a messagebox, can you? Btw you can use this oneliner for the above $(Get-WMIObject -class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object username).username

Comment: I'm not 100% certain given your use case.

Comment: Or even shorter - (Get-WMIObject -class Win32_ComputerSystem).Username --- or --- (Get-WMIObject Win32_ComputerSystem).Username --- or --- (gwmi $Win32_ComputerSystem).Username. As for interacting with it, outside of dismissing it, nope.

Comment: @postanote Great work! The smaller, the better!